# Open maplotlib window with PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pysimplegui

I am very new to PySimpleGUI and I am getting stuck on a certain part of my code. I have some data of which I want to make a plot using matplotlib and I can get it to be opened in a canvas in the PySimpleGUI window but what I would like to achieve is for the figure to be plotted in a separate window (preferably the matplotlib window) so that it becomes easy to save the figure on my computer.

I was wondering if there is a simple way of doing it. Essentially what I want to obtain is to press a button 'Plot' in PySimpleGUI and then obtain my plot in a window such as this:

[Example window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIC6p.png)

My code is currently quite large and not very optimized (it only works for the specific dataset I am using for now) so if I need to share the code I have please let me know and I can create a simple code as an example. If someone could explain to me how I can achieve my goal directly that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just `plt` your figure and call `plt.show(block=False)` under `if event == 'Plot':` in your event loop.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

year = [1920,1930,1940,1950,1960,1970,1980,1990,2000,2010]
unemployment_rate = [9.8,12,8,7.2,6.9,7,6.5,6.2,5.5,6.3]

def create_plot(year, unemployment_rate):
    plt.plot(year, unemployment_rate, color='red', marker='o')
    plt.title('Unemployment Rate Vs Year', fontsize=14)
    plt.xlabel('Year', fontsize=14)
    plt.ylabel('Unemployment Rate', fontsize=14)
    plt.grid(True)
    return

layout = [[sg.Button('Show')]]
window = sg.Window('Demo Application - Embedding Matplotlib In PySimpleGUI', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    elif event == 'Show':
        create_plot(year, unemployment_rate)
        plt.show(block=False)

window.close()
```